# Why immer.js doesn't allow setting dynamic properties on draft?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutability, immer.js

```js
//I want my action to dispatch payload like
// {type:'update',payload:{'current.contact.mobile':'XXXXXXXXX'}}
//In reducer dynamically select the segment of state update needs to be applied to 
//Below code doesn't work as expected though, draft always remains at same level
draft = dA.key.split('.').reduce((draft, k) => {
  return draft[k]
}, draft);

//Or an ideal syntax may look like below line
draft['current.contact.mobile'] = dA.value;


//Code that works
draft['current']['contact']['mobile'] = dA.value;
```

I want my action to dispatch payload like
{type:'update',payload:{'current.contact.mobile':'XXXXXXXXX'}}
And in reducer dynamically select the segment of state that needs to be updated. 
Is there something fundamentally wrong in doing this, I believe this could make life easier. Is there something that can done to achieve this  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, this code returns [a primitive value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) like a string or number which is immutable.

```
draft = dA.key.split('.').reduce((draft, k) => {
  return draft[k]
}, draft);
```

"Immer" is using [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to implement all this magic. The proxy could work only on objects for example Object, Array, Function etc.

so to fix your problem you can use code like this

```
import produce from "immer";

describe("Why immer.js doesn't allow setting dynamic properties on draft?", function() {
  it("should allow set dynamic properties", function() {
    const path = "foo.bar.zoo";
    const state = { foo: { bar: { zoo: 1 } } };
    const nextState = produce(state, draft => {
      const vector = path.split(".");
      const propName = vector.pop();

      if (propName) {
        draft = vector.reduce((it, prop) => it[prop], draft);
        draft[propName] += 1;
      }
    });

    expect(nextState.foo.bar.zoo).toEqual(state.foo.bar.zoo + 1);
  });
});
```

In the code above, we get destination **object** and **update the property** of this object.

*Some note about string and number*.
Javascript has [constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript) for string and number which return **objects** not primitive values. But this is a very rare case when someone uses it explicitly.
Usually, we deal with it implicitly when writing something like this `dA.key.split('.')`. In this case, the interpreter would create a string object and call method "split" on it. Usually, this behavior is referred to as "*Boxing*"

Comment: Nice explanation, but if anyone wants to hide that logic by using Lodash you can do `set(draft, path, newValue)`